# How do I install maintenance module from odoo9 mrp module?

Tags: odoo-9

Please let me know how do I install and use maintenance module from odoo9 mrp module?

please give some reference for this

Comment: from odoo9 manufacturing module

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is activate the below setting by going to: Manufacturing > Configuration > Settings > Preventive and Corrective maintenance management. Apply the change, it should refresh your page, then you will have a new app in the app picker (top left button).

[image: Manufacturing > Configuration > Settings > Preventive and Corrective maintenance management]

Comment: Thank you Sir, but in odoo9 manufacturing module->configuration-->settings->here there is no Extra features...only i have Manufacturing order feature....so How do I get Extra features in odoo9 manufacturing....pls let me know

Comment: @chapel Sorry, I didn't realize your question was specific to Odoo 9. As far as I know, the [Maintenance module](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/mrp_maintenance/) is only available for Odoo 10. Same with Quality and PLM. All of them were introduced in 10, with no plans to backport.